# Randomly Sample Raster Pixels With a Minimum Distance in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, random, autocorrelation, sample

Is there a way I can sample random raster pixels from a satellite image with QGIS or QGIS plugin?   I also need each randomly-chosen pixel to have a pre-defined minimum distance from the other raster pixels. I need this pre-defined minimum distance in order to minimize spatial autocorrelation.

Comment: What is your desired output? A table with the values? A new raster wherein the randomly selected pixels are the only non-NA values?

Comment: I want to sample random raster pixels with minimum distance and output as a tiff file.